# Item metadata not overriding property metadata

Tags: msbuild

How do I get an Item's metadata to override a Item definitions metadata?

I have in my vcxproj with:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PNL Include="some file">
    <OutputDirectory>y</OutputDirectory>
  </PNL>
</ItemGroup>
```

I then have a .props file with:

```
<PNL>
  <OutputDirectory>x</OutputDirectory>
  <CommandLineTemplate>%(OutputDirectory)</CommandLineTemplate>
</PNL>
```

And a .target file with:

```
<PNL>
  OutputDirectory="%(PNL.OutputDirectory)"
  Outputs="%(PNL.Outputs)"
  CommandLineTemplate="%(PNL.CommandLineTemplate)"
</PNL>
```

So I would expect that the Items metadata overrides the metadata in the .props file such that 
the command line equates to: y
but visual studio is giving me: x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. Instead of putting CommandLineTemplate in the .props file, and having the .target file referencing %(PNL.CommandLineTemplate)

I simply put the command in the target file:
CommandLineTemplate="%(PNL.OutputDirectory)"

Answer (score 0):

Item metadata is something which is specific for each particular **item**, not for a whole **item array**. You can think about it as a separate *dictionary* assigned for each particular *item* in *item array*.

So in you sample first in .prop file you are trying to assign specific dictionary to 'empty' item array, then in vcxproj file you are just defining new item with its own metadata, and use it.

You can not define 'default' metadata for all 'future' items.

What you can do is to create separate target in .prop file, which will add metadata for each of **already defined** items, and call it when you need.

Answer (score 0):

According to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx#BKMK_Transforming

Under "Item Definitions":

> Starting in the .NET Framework 3.5, you can add default metadata to any item type by using the ItemDefinitionGroup element. Like well-known metadata, the default metadata is associated with all items of the item type that you specify. You can explicitly override default metadata in an item definition.

Which is what I am doing is it not?